# What is passed from parameter userId in SocialUserDetailsService? and how to override it?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-social, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to use spring social authentication and fetch the user according to the `facebook user id` which is stored in my User entity.

To do this I'm doing something like this.

```
@Component("socialUserDetailsService")
public class SecSocialUserDetailService implements SocialUserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private SecUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public SocialUserDetails loadUserByUserId(String userId) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        return userDetailsService.loadUserByFacebookId(userId);
    }
}
```

But

1. I have no idea what is passed in this `userId` parameter from the facebook profile?
2. If I need to override the value to something like an `email` of facebook profile. how can I do it?

Comment: do you want to provide "sign in with" functionality or you just want to "connect" your (already registered) users to FB etc? However check http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#section_persistingConnections that's how spring social connects "social identities" with your local identities

Comment: Thank you :). I want to do both. Sign up new users and connect already registered users. But for the moment. here in this question, concentrating on the connect already registered user is sufficient

Comment: then answer to your first question is that `userId` is your local user identification (i.e. login name for your local users) but I don't understand your second question.

Comment: I thought this is the user identification fetched from the facebook. Also internally, i'm using the primary key as an integer and username as the authentication identification. Username can be changed. That's the reason I want to load the user by something like email. Anyhow if this is the userId from spring auth and not from facebook, then my second question is invalid. :) thank you for your response.

Comment: spring social uses `ConnectionRepositorty` (for details see the link above) to map social identities to your local identities. you can allow one user to be logged in via FB or twitter but from your point of view it is only one identity.